# Is there a way to do context sensitive parsing in tatsu

Tags: tatsu

context sensitive '%' ..... eol comments

I'm starting with the grammar for PDF described here

https://github.com/caradoc-org/caradoc/blob/master/doc/grammar/grammar.pdf

which seems to lack the definition of eol comments.

PDF has end of line comments which start with the '%' character except inside string_literal (and another rule stream).

```
string_literal = "(" string_content ")";
```

where string_content can include the '%' character and also eol, but not "()" etc. The PDF language also has some special cases which otherwise look like comments eg

```
'%PDF-1.5' eol;
```

or

```
"%%EOF" [eol];
```

is there a way to handle the context sensitivity in  a tatsu grammar?

Answer (score 1):

I'll stay away from "Context Sensitive" in this answer, because the phrase has meaning in Language Theory.

PEG is perfectly capable of parsing a sub-language (say, Python string formatting expressions) within another language.

In fact, the original PEG definition *does not* use a tokenizer, because PEG grammars can parse the token sub-language.

If you think of sub-grammars, then the context is provided by the rule that knows that a sub-grammar has to be invoked.

With TatSu, there are features that allow tokenization to happen before the parsing (the `Buffer` class) for efficiency, and convenience, but using those features is not mandatory.

The only cases that cannot be handled easily as a grammar-within-a-grammar are preprocessing with macro capabilities, because those require an interpretation phase before the text for the inner grammar can be parsed.